# SVG gaussian blur feature detection

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to detect if browser supports SVG blurring for elements. I did find a [script](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/filters.js) that does that for CSS filters() blur, but I also want to detect if browser supports SVG gaussian blur.

I found a script that detects SVG blur, but it returns true on IE10/IE11 even though it didn't blur HTML element. I am using [Vague.js](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js/) to blur an element.

```
svgBlur = function() {
    var svgBlur = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'feGaussianBlur');
    svgBlur.setAttribute('stdDeviation', '2');
    return (typeof svgBlur.setStdDeviation !== 'undefined');
}();
```

Is there a realiable way to detect SVG blur for elements, so I can successfully create a fallback?

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr

Comment: Blurring of non-SVG elements by SVG filters is something that's only implemented by Firefox currently. IE10/11 will blur SVG elements which is why your script returns true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect it programmatically, you'd need to do three things:

- Take a reference screenshot manually
- Take a live screenshot programmatically
- Compare the two programmatically

Here are some resources:

- [Canvas Diff](http://jonathan-olson.com/canvas-diff/canvas-diff.html)
- [JS-imagediff](http://humblesoftware.github.io/js-imagediff/)
- [The Road to HTML5: Automating visual testing with Sikuli](http://www.gliffy.com/blog/2012/07/12/the-road-to-html5-automating-visual-testing-with-sikuli/)